# Get index of argument with xargs?

Tags: bash, sorting, file-sorting

In bash, I have list of files all named the same (in different sub directories) and I want to order them by creation/modified time, something like this:

```
ls -1t /tmp/tmp-*/my-file.txt | xargs ...
```

I would like to rename those files with some sort of index or something so I can move them all into the same folder. My result would ideally be something like:

```
my-file0.txt
my-file1.txt
my-file2.txt
```

Something like that. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

You can just loop through these files and keep appending an incrementing counter to desired file name:

```
for f in /tmp/tmp-*/my-file.txt; do
   fname="${f##*/}"
   fname="${fname%.*}"$((i++)).txt

   mv "$f" "/dest/dir/$fname"
done
```

---

**EDIT:** In order to sort listed files my modification time as is the case with `ls -1t` you can use this script:

```
while IFS= read -d '' -r f; do
   f="${f#* }"
   fname="${f##*/}"
   fname="${fname%.*}"$((i++)).txt

   mv "$f" "/dest/dir/$fname"
done < <(find /tmp/tmp-* -name 'my-file.txt' -printf "%T@ %p\0" | sort -zk1nr)
```

This handles filenames with all special characters like white spaces, newlines, glob characters etc since we are ending each filename with NUL or `\0` character in `-printf` option. Note that we are also using `sort -z` to handle NUL terminated data.

Comment: They are in the same dir, first sub isn't needed

Comment: Hmm but `$f` will be `/tmp/tmp-foo/my-file.txt` or `/tmp/tmp-bar/my-file.txt` and desired output is `my-file0.txt`, `my-file1.txt` etc.. so we do need to strip path of filename.

Comment: Actually yeah, i think I misunderstood the question, nvm :)

Comment: This misses the sort-by-modification-time aspect of the question.

Comment: @chepner is right, looking to have sort criteria. Thanks though!

Comment: It's a little better I guess, still looks really complicated for a relatively simple task. Assigning fname twice seems dirty. I'll stick with the simpler awk solution. Thanks though!

Comment: Your `awk` solution might look simpler but it is faulty since you're parsing output of `ls`.

Comment: Why can't you parse the output of ls? I see you've mentioned that several times. It seems like pretty common practice...

Comment: I have provided a link of BASH FAQ in a comment below your answer that explains why it should not be done. Chepner also provide that link in his comment on other answer.

Answer (score 1):

So I found an answer to my own question, thoughts on this one?

```
ls -1t /tmp/tmp-*/my-file.txt  | awk 'BEGIN{ a=0 }{ printf "cp %s /tmp/all-the-files/my-file_%03d.txt\n", $0, a++ }' | bash;
```

I found this from another stack overflow question looking for something similar that my search didn't find at first. I was impressed with the awk line, thought that was pretty neat.

Comment: I could easily write my answer with `ls -1t` but parsing output of `ls` must be avoided.

Comment: @anubhava why is that? How else would you sort the files? Your answer did not provide any sorting.

Comment: Check edited part in my answer for sorting. [Check this on why output of `ls` should not be parsed](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)